# WCF for mobile: what's the difference

Tags: wcf, windows-mobile

We will write WCF service for our windows mobile client. Although we have the experience in WCF development, we know there are some difference when developing wcf for mobile. 
Can you tell me where I can find the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Windows Communication Foundation (Compact Edition) and the story of the Lunch Launcher](http://blogs.msdn.com/romanbat/archive/2006/10/21/windows-communication-foundation-compact-edition-and-the-story-of-the-lunch-launcher.aspx)  and [Write an IM App with the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164240.aspx)